# How much should I pay attention to the f1 score on this case?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, prediction, model-evaluations

I trained a model with results as below. It is a stacking model with base learners of random forest and gradient boosting. The mega model is a GLM. The dataset is imbalanced in the target class as shown in the confusion matrix on the right top. The target class is a default status of a single loan (Positive: default; Negative: non-default).

The AUC ROC score is quite high but the f1 score is still only 0.53. My concern is both of recall and precision were approximately 0.5, meaning that the model can only distinguish half of the bad cases and only half of bad cases it diagnosed were truly bad.

If I adjust the probabilistic threshold, recall will increase but precision will also be sacrificed to some extent. Due to the highly imbalanced situation on the positive cases, a low precision may lead to a large proportion of False Negative among the predicted positive cases. e.g. under a lower precision, if a model tells 10 bad cases, there may be actually only 2 truly bad ones and more fake bad ones predicted which is not wanted in practice as well.

In predictive task on an imbalanced dataset, does f1 score matter and if so how can I further improve the score? (add new (composite) features, cost sensitive methods?)

[image]

Before asking this question, I have read the [paper](http://www.pitt.edu/~jeffcohn/biblio/Jeni_Metrics.pdf) and get to know the skew of data does impact f1 score. But how to improve this case and reach a better predictive outcome for the practice.

[image]

Comment: Give me a comment rather than rashly a down vote. I think the site here is set to help people grow, not judge without comments. Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/18495/8560, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274870/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @D.W.  I don't think anybody had their time wasted here. Two sites did not have the same visitor population. I just wanna more people to get to the problem which really got me stuck and I seek for helps. Those who had already seen it would ignore it. Besides, cross-posted was more than often due to no response in certain site and I have to resort to another. Cheers

Comment: I do understand your motivations and sympathize with the desire to get as many people as possible to read your question, but those are the rules of the site (see the link I provided for details).  My goal is to let you know for the future -- please avoid cross-posting future questions -- and to inform anyone else who may stumble on this question.  Thank you for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, F1 matters.  It is telling you that your classifier is basically a coin toss for true positives.  AUC and accuracy are high because of all the negatives.  So, how can you improve your score?
Try this:
http://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/

Comment: Thanks for comments and sharing. But high AUC may not be caused by majority of negative cases.  I have read the link months ago and what it suggested does not particularly fit well my problem here but thanks.

Comment: @LUSAQX, I guess I don't understand your question.  Why are you concerned with finding a scoring method that makes your model look better than it is?  The best way to improve the score is improve the model.

Comment: I think the model is sufficiently good in terms of AUC ROC score. But if I deploy the model into practice, the low f1 score would lead to a relatively poor performance on classification ( 0.5 accuracy under the probabilistic threshold shown.) The future data is also imbalanced, so too many false positive will be predicted comparing to the true positive.